# play.db.ebean.Model.delete() override not being called on child

Tags: playframework, ebean

The parent entity has the following child:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="s3script_id")
@JsonIgnore
public S3File scriptFile;
```

The S3File entity extends play.db.ebean.Model and overrides the delete() method (to clean up the S3 files, besides my DB entries). Upon deleting the parent, the overridden delete() method is not called. However, cascade delete works and the child entity *is* deleted in the database.

On the other hand, if I specifically call delete() on the child object, the overridden delete() method is called.